# How is a request to the token endpont build by ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder?

Tags: .net, http, microsoft-entra-id

I have an endpoint that requires authentication via entra id.

I can request a valid token for it using

```
  static async Task Main(string[] args)
  {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

      await EnsureAuthorizationHeader(client);

      var res = await client.GetAsync("https://mydomain/myendpoint");
 
  }
  
private static async Task EnsureAuthorizationHeader(HttpClient result)
 {
     IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
         .Create(ApplicationId)
         .WithClientSecret(ApplicationSecret)
         .WithAuthority(Instance.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + TenantId)
         .Build();

     string[] scopes = new[] { $"api://{DownstreamApplicationId}/.default" };

     AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

     authenticationResult = await confidentialClientApplication
         .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();


     result.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
         "Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken
     );
 }
```

The generated token has an audience in

```
  "aud": "api://[id of my application]",
```

Since I need to request the token by curl I tried to use

[image]

This gives my a token but I cant access my api with it. The token also does not have a value in aud

```
 "aud": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
```

What does the request of ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder look like? I cant use fiddler right now.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, I used the wrong endpoint to retrieve the token. Once I changed

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/[mytennantid]/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Bmytennantid%5D/oauth2/token)

to

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/[mytennantid]/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5Bmytennantid%5D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

everything started to work.